# Failed while trying to upload file to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I registered a snowflake trail account and I tried to upload local file to snowflake. following the tutorial https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-internal-tutorial.html

I am on windows platform and it is failing when I run the put command.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-stage-data-files.html​
The error is

john#MYWAREHOUSE@MYDATABASE.PUBLIC>put file://c:\temp\load\contacts*.csv @my_csv_stage auto_compress=true;

Unable to parse config file: C:\Users\john/.aws/credentials
Could you please help on that?

Comment: Are you using snowsql to upload the file?

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to upload a file to a S3 stage for which you don't have the proper credentials.

Try to run this instead -

```
put file://c:\temp\load\contacts*.csv @~ auto_compress=true;
```